# Ms Access - Updating an image from a combobox column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox where someone can select from a list of people in a database.

Combobox appears like this

```
ID    Name      Class_ID    Image_ID    
1     John Doe  1           /Path to Image (short text)
```

I would like like an Image in an Access form to show the Image_ID based on the combobox value that is selected. E.g Person 1 is selected in combobox -> Person 1's id image appears.

I've tried setting the control source of the image to be 
`=[cboPeople].Column(3)` but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of image?  Where are they stored?  (is it a local `path`? network? web?)  Also how many images?

Comment: .png file that is stored on a network drive. One image per record. Currently stored the image file path as a short text in the database.

Comment: Are you using an Image Form Control?  How are you sure?  Much more information would be helpful.

Comment: I think issue is using `.Controlsource` property - use `.Picture`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the problem is you're trying to set the `.ControlSource` property. If this is an Image Control you should be able to reset the display by setting the `.Picture` property as in

```
Dim strImagePath as String
strImagePath = [cboPeople].Column(3)
MyImageControl.Picture = strImagePath
```

Or just try assigning directly

```
MyImageControl.Picture=[cboPeople].Column(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me

```
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Image0.Picture = Me.Combo1
End Sub
```

[image]